# Encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

What I'd like to know is simple.
Can I use OpenSSL to encrypt a string "hello" with a private key then send it to everyone who can decrypt it with the public key to retrieve the original string.

I've searched all around and can't really find anything.

Mathematically I can use the private exponent and public modulus to perform an encryption then use the public exponent and public modulus to perform the decryption.

Can I do this with OpenSSL?

I've read that this is considered signing. 
Then how can I sign with my private key and receive the original data from the signed file with just the public key?

I've read a lot of the responses on the web and they're all vague. 
Can anyone give me clear solutions?

If it is possible to encrypt with a private key and decrypt with public can anyone give me an example on how to do it with the openssl tool? Or do I have to write my own implementation?

Comment: OpenSSL comes with a command line tool that performs various functions, including signing and signature validation. Since OpenSSL is open source, you can simply examine how that code does those things. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20813730/315052) for a start.

Comment: When you say, "Can I do this with OpenSSL", do you mean the command-line tool `openssl` or `libcrypto`, the cryptographic algorithms library? There is a difference. One involves writing code. The answer to *both* is *yes*, but the mechanics in doing so are obviously different.

Comment: If you're trying to do this through libcrypto, look into the RSA functions for example. Like [generating key pairs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html), and [encrypting](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html) and [decrypting](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302168/1462337

Comment: Well I did mean the command-line tool openssl. But libcrypto would be fine too. But @WhozCraig you said the answer to both is yes. Could you provide any examples on how to do this? And I don't mind writing my own implementation, I'm wondering if the means to do so is currently available.

Comment: Please don't clobber your own question like this. I've rolled back your edit. If you think the question is not useful, you can delete it.

Comment: "Encrypt with the private key" is not a vlid crypto operation, despite the results of `grep -R -i private_encrypt *` in OpenSSL. Perhaps you want a [Signature Scheme with Recovery](http://www.google.com/search?q="Signature+Scheme+with+Recovery").

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes. I already flagged it, now I need it to be deleted.

Comment: @StackPointer - I rolled back the changes; please don't take it personally. Its easier on everyone when the questions stays about the same. If you want to delete it, then flag it for the moderators (which you did). They will get to it in time. I'll up vote it for you since you are trying to do the right thing. That will offset the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting with the private key is not considered signing. Using RSA, there is in fact encryption using the private key, but this is just an implementation detail of RSA, and it is not encrypting the message, but a hash of the message, so no, verifying the signature does not bring back the original plaintext message.

Yes you can sign and verify signatures in OpenSSL -- cf. https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_sign.html

No, you should not use "textbook RSA" with the modulus and exponent to roll your own encryption. Cf. here, for example: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa

No, you should not swap the use of the private and public keys by encrypting data with the private key and decrypting with the public. Cf. for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2350959/233596.

UPDATE:

[This page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html) suggests that you can use the OpenSSL C interface to encrypt with the private key and decrypt with the public key, by way of these function prototypes:

```
 int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
 int RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
 int RSA_private_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa,int padding);
 int RSA_public_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, 
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa,int padding);
```

(I did not actually try using these functions.)

I tried using the openssl rsautl command line:

```
$ openssl rsautl -in HELLO -out HELLO.encrypt_by_private -inkey private.pem -encrypt
```

However:

```
$ openssl rsautl -in  HELLO.encrypt_by_private -pubin -inkey public.pem -decrypt
A private key is needed for this operation
```

So, I would say that the command line tool will not do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's not really a matter of "playing with fire" it's just a simple yes or no, can I do it. I want to be able to encrypt with my private key. I was refering to the openssl tool, not the library it had used. But does the current implementation not support encrypting the actual data, rather than the hash of the data?

Comment: @StackPointer I updated my answer. I would guess that the C interface will do it (I did not actually try it), but that the command-line tool will not let you swap the keys around.

Comment: The "This page" link in the update is now a dead link.

Comment: @JWWalker argh. Anyway, I had copied the info of interest. I doubt there was much more interesting on that page than the prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Signing and encrypting are two entirely different concepts. It wouldn't make much sense to encrypt something with your private key and then distribute it to be encrypted with your public key. Your public key is inherently available, being that it is public, which defeats the purpose of encrypting.

Traditionally, encryption is done with someone else's public key in a way that permits the message to be decrypted only with the private key.

Signing, on the other, generally involves hashing the message using your private key as a seed value. Using the public key you hash the message again and compare your hash to the original hash. If they correspond (they won't be identical), then you have verified that the only possible sender is the holder of the private key (which may or may not be who you believe it is, if that has been compromised)

Comment: Yes but it's not a matter of why I should or shouldn't do it. I have reasons for wanting to do it.

Comment: This is a bad answer. There are scenarios where it totally makes sense to encrypt the data with the private key and decrypt it with the public key.